# Creating example shiny application installer included in RInno package produces an error related to 'namespace:jsonlite'

Tags: r, json, shiny

I am following the steps described in [Deploying R shiny app as a standalone application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33513544/deploying-r-shiny-app-as-a-standalone-application/43349551) to create an example Shiny application.

I have already installed "RInno" package from github (ficonsulting/RInno).

In empty R project I executed the following code.

```
library(shiny)
library(RInno)

example_app(app_dir = "app") 

create_app(app_name = "myapp", app_dir = "app")
#The step above produces an error: 'write_json' is not an exported object from 'namespace:jsonlite'

compile_iss()
```

Which fails with an error. How to resolve this issue?

```
    > sessionInfo()
    R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
    Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
    Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

    locale:
    [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
    [3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
    [5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

    attached base packages:
    [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

    other attached packages:
    [1] rjson_0.2.15         jsonlite_1.1         RInno_0.2.0          shiny_1.0.5.9000    
    [5] dplyr_0.7.4.9001     purrr_0.2.4          readr_1.0.0          tidyr_0.6.0         
    [9] tibble_1.4.2         ggplot2_2.2.1.9000   tidyverse_1.0.0      RevoUtilsMath_10.0.0
    [13] RevoUtils_10.0.2     RevoMods_10.0.0      MicrosoftML_1.0.0    mrsdeploy_1.0       
    [17] RevoScaleR_9.0.1     lattice_0.20-34      rpart_4.1-10        

    loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
    [1] Rcpp_0.12.16.1         later_0.7.1            pillar_1.1.0          
    [4] plyr_1.8.4             bindr_0.1.1.9000       iterators_1.0.8       
    [7] tools_3.3.2            digest_0.6.10          mrupdate_1.0.0        
    [10] gtable_0.2.0           pkgconfig_2.0.1        rlang_0.2.0.9001      
    [13] foreach_1.4.3          CompatibilityAPI_1.1.0 curl_2.2              
    [16] yaml_2.1.13            bindrcpp_0.2.0.9000    withr_2.1.1.9000      
    [19] grid_3.3.2             tidyselect_0.2.3       glue_1.2.0            
    [22] R6_2.2.2               magrittr_1.5           promises_0.1.0.9002   
    [25] htmltools_0.3.5        scales_0.5.0.9000      codetools_0.2-15      
    [28] assertthat_0.2.0       xtable_1.8-2           mime_0.5              
    [31] colorspace_1.2-7       httpuv_1.3.6.9006      lazyeval_0.2.0        
    [34] munsell_0.4.3
```

Comment: I think you should post this on the [git hub](https://github.com/ficonsulting/RInno/issues) page.

Comment: I did it https://github.com/ficonsulting/RInno/issues/66

Answer (score 0):

I believe this issue is caused by an older version of jsonlite. RInno requires jsonlite >=1.5.