# Possibility of getting offline shinyApp without Publish Button, csv Data and seeing R code?

Tags: r, csv, shiny, dashboard, shinydashboard

Hi guys i have made a shinyApp for a client using **R**.

The client for whom I’m working is asking for a shinyapp that **works offline** preferably in the form of an application or shiny window (as the online link of shinyapp.io will put load on the server). He wants to get the **shiny output without seeing the R code**.

He will later handover the shinyApp to his employees (>200) and they will mostly use the offline shinyApp on their desktop **(in shiny window)**. Furthermore the **data is very confidential** so the client doesn't want his employees to either get csv data or publish the app online or see R code. Because every time they would  run the app, they require csv data or codes to generate output. 
That's why he doesn’t want a publish button anywhere in the app so that his employees doesn’t publish the app online.

Is there any way to do so? Any suggestions would be much appreciated

Comment: I would run a local server in the company network restricted to only local IPs.

Comment: Hi Alexandar, is there some other way to hide codes, publish button

Comment: I think you can disable the publish button. I found this: [link](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/210990438-Disabling-RStudio-Features). However, hiding the code in RStudio is not possible, because it is the core of its sense. I think it should be possible to start the R/shiny script via the commandline. This would prevent the users to see the code directly, i.e. a win.exe or shortcut that start the script via R commandline.

Comment: Thanks mate, i can't find much details or codes to disable **publish** button

Answer (score 2):

Method 1

I feel this is the [best way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43349551/10974563) to do it. This will give you an exe setup to install on your clients' server If you find it complicated you can try the below method, but my first preference would be this one.

Method 2

The process of making your standalone app is best explained [here](http://blog.analytixware.com/2014/03/packaging-your-shiny-app-as-windows.html).

You can also use this [site](https://www.r-bloggers.com/deploying-desktop-apps-with-r/). If you feel the first is a little ambiguous

It is very much possible, and I do it often. If you have any doubts, you can ask me. This will not show the code to your client, it will be like any other desktop/server app, although the code can be seen if the app is probed, unlike the first method.

You can put the packaged app in a server which serves the local IPs.
I think you can do it without any hassle. Just follow the instructions line by line.

Regards/Revanth Nemani

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, I used method 2 (AnalytixWare), but anyone can go in my shiny folder to access R code file along with csv data. Is it possible to put restriction on Shiny folder having both files

Comment: i tried using method 1, but RInno::install_inno() is giving me an error '*unsupported 16bit application, github can't start due to incompatibility with 64bit versions of windows*'

Comment: I am currently making a repex and I'll let you know the challenges involved. I've never really faced that particular error. Let me do some probing and get back to you in a day or two.

Comment: sorry for the late reply, refer to this [GitHub RInno issue](https://github.com/ficonsulting/RInno/issues/118)