# Mac OS Shiny Executable

Tags: r, shiny, executable

Many of the resources for making a Shiny executable application are Windows-specific (e.g. RInno, StackOverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33513544/deploying-r-shiny-app-as-a-standalone-application))

How could one set this up for Mac OS-X?

Comment: Maybe building an [Electron app with Shiny](https://github.com/ksasso/Electron_ShinyApp_Deployment)?

Comment: Here's a talk on [using Electron for Shiny app deployment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ARrbbviGvjc).

Comment: Reading through tutorials, I have ended up on [this](https://www.r-bloggers.com/shell-script-to-build-os-x-shiny-apps-from-github-gists/) page. However it says "A future post will show how to make a Mac OS X Shiny app from a local ui.R, server.R and any associated support/data files". Does anyone knows if there is something new about it?