# How to create desktop stanalone app fro shiny code

Tags: r, shiny

I have written a GUI code in R shiny. Now I want to create a desktop stand alone app (.exe file) for the same.
How can I do that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deploying R shiny app as a standalone application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33513544/deploying-r-shiny-app-as-a-standalone-application)