# Mobile shiny app that runs offline, no connectivity

Tags: r, shiny, progressive-web-apps

I am trying to make a [shiny](/questions/tagged/shiny) app that can be used on a smart phone without connectivity.

I have found several examples of [shiny](/questions/tagged/shiny) apps being bundled into something convenient and run on a desktop or mobile device, but they all still require an internet connection. I want the mobile app to be able to run locally with no connectivity.

The closest thing I have seen is making a [shiny](/questions/tagged/shiny) app into a Progressive Web App (PWA). PWAs in general do have the ability to run without connectivity, but [shiny](/questions/tagged/shiny) PWAs that I have found still require connectivity.

List of similar resources:

- [shiny](/questions/tagged/shiny) as standalone [electron](/questions/tagged/electron) app (not for mobile) [Deploying R shiny app as a standalone application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33513544/deploying-r-shiny-app-as-a-standalone-application)
- PWAs for shiny https://github.com/pedrocoutinhosilva/shiny.pwa
- [shinymobile](/questions/tagged/shinymobile) - does create PWA https://rinterface.github.io/shinyMobile/

From what I can tell, all these and others still require internet connection, though.

Any options for an app that can run on a smart phone without connectivity?

Comment: Shiny apps run all your R code on the server. You cannot run shiny apps without a server, and you can't run a server on your smart phone. If you need to run without a connection to a server, shiny probably isn't the right solution for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For an epidemiological cohort study, a Shiny app was developed to run completely offline in Android mobile devices. The app was designed for field level data capture. The code to setup the Android devices so that the Shiny app runs locally, offline, was published in GitHub, https://github.com/dmrodz/htrack. The *installation_and_dependencies* section contains the setup needed for the mobile device to run R (and the app) and deploy in the default browser (offline/locally).

The development of this app was peer-reviewed:

Rodríguez, D.M., Ryff, K., Sánchez-Gonzalez, L., Rivera-Amill, V., Paz-Bailey, G., Adams, L. (2020). *HTrack: A new tool to facilitate public health field visits and electronic data capture. PLoS ONE 15(12): e0244028*. https://doi.org/10.1371/journal.pone.0244028

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thank you! I added supporting information as applicable.