# Hosting LAN Shiny apps run from command line

Tags: r, rstudio, shiny-server, shiny

I am trying to host a Shiny app on a machine hooked up to a LAN.  In the directory housing my app, I have the server.R, ui.R, and launcher.R scripts.  The launcher.R file looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript
library(shiny)
setwd("~/path/to/shinyApp/")
shiny::runApp(host="0.0.0.0",port=4414)
```

When I run this via RStudio, the app launches, behaves normally, and can be accessed by other machines through the LAN by going to 987.65.43.21:4414 in a browser. When I run the app with `launch.browser=T`, the address reads 127.0.0.1:4414.

I want to be able to run the launcher and host the app without RStudio running.  When I try running the launcher code via command line, the app gives the usual messages

```
Loading required package: methods
Listening on http://0.0.0.0:4414
```

but I cannot access the app through a LAN browser.  If I navigate to the 127.0.0.1:4414 on the host machine, I can access it, but not via the machine's IP on another machine like I could when running RStudio.

Does anyone have any insight on what could be going on?  Thanks!

Comment: I'm interested in knowing if you found a solution here. It's obviously been a while since this was posted, but I'm in a situation where I can only host my script on a windows device (so `shiny-server` is not an option), I'm not ready to share this on shiny io, and I want my other users to be able to start this script up without having to open R. Any luck?

Comment: Hi @Dorton, its been a long time since I though about this but I ended up just leaving Rstudio running in the background.  Not the most satisfying ending to the story unfortunately!

Answer (score 2):

Install shiny-server from [here](https://www.rstudio.com/products/shiny/download-server/) this will allow you to access your shiny apps from your LAN. Just put your shiny files in `/srv/shiny-server/myApp` and you can access them through `xx.xx.xx.xx:3838/myApp/`

Comment: Thanks for the idea; the machine I am trying to use as a host is a Mac, which isn't supported for Shiny Server. I may try to compile from source, but any ideas for how to make it work without Shiny Server?