# Shiny putting app into production

Tags: r, shiny

I have created my first Shiny app and i want to share it with people.
I have a folder which contains my ui.R file and my Server.R file.

I have managed to get a server for it and install Shiny Server and it runs pretty well. In fact I have written the shiny app in the web browser.

My question is where do I save the scripts on the shiny server so that I can send the link to people and it will just load up as a website (assuming they have credentials?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another question similiar to the one i was looking for.

[Hosting LAN Shiny apps run from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34163558/hosting-lan-shiny-apps-run-from-command-line)

This answers the question by specifiying that i should move my test scripts into production by saving them `/srv/shiny-server/myApp`

Answer (score 0):

Which server do you use? Perhaps AWS (Amazon)? Then you can upload it in one of the folders on your server. In the case of Amazon, you do it through S3 Browser.

You can use a domain name to redirect you to the specific folder where you keep your shiny apps. Each shiny app should have its own sub-directory where you keep server and ui scripts. Then you load your shiny name like this:
yourdomain.com/sub_directory_where_shiny_script_are_located

Don't forget to adjust your directories in the script, so that when you load any data, it loads the data located on ubuntu server, for example.

```
if(Sys.info()[['user']] %in% c("ubuntu","shiny") ) {
  load("/a2cka/ShinyApps/sub_directory_shin_app_/data.csv}
```